# Simple, inexpensive concurrent list or set?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

Let's say I could have thousands of objects of a certain type, and in each object there is one field for a List or set, but this list or set needs to be concurrent. A concurrent hashmap in each of hundreds or thousands of objects seems like overkill (or is it?). I also needs an atomic put-if-absent operation in each list/set. Is a ConcurrentHashMap overkill or too expensive? Is there a more lightweight alternative? I'd prefer not to do a synchronized set or list...

Comment: How many items do you expect to be in each concurrent list or set, on average?

Comment: Forgive me for using a cliché, but … premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Trying using a ConcurrentHashMap, and worry about efficiency if and only if you find it's a bottleneck.  JIT optimization is pretty good at such things.  Though, for what it's worth, I would synchronize on a regular HashSet or TreeSet, since [Set.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) is already a put-if-absent operation.

Comment: Just use a ConcurrentHashMap<T, Object> and stuff in a placeholder value and use the ket set as the set you want. What you're describing is basically a ConcurrentHashSet, it just doesn't exist.

Comment: For any count between 50 and 500,000, I'd worry more about the concurrent access patterns than if it's too expensive.

Comment: I would try it using the easiest implementation first, and only if there's a problem look for something exotic. Frankly, a few thousand isn't that many.

Comment: I am actually in an optimization situation on an existing design. I will have to run some tests between ConcurrentHashMap and a synchronized HashSet. I anticipate simultaneous reading and writing will be frequent hence why I wanted to strive for concurrency and not synchronization. But I won't know the benefit until I measure.

Comment: The default answer for any question simultaneously containing the words "simple," "inexpensive," and "concurrent" is "doesn't exist."

Comment: Alright I just went ahead with implementing a synchronized set and it got the job done. I could go with extracting the set from a ConcurrentHashMap but I don't know if its worth the overhead. I've already crunched this 30 second operation into a 2-second operation using concurrency and synchronized sets. I think I'm fine with this performance and don't need to pursue more overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is concurrent CopyOnWriteArraySet which is good only for sets which rarely change.

Another option is to make a Set from ConcurrentHashMap

```
Set<Object> set1 = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Boolean>());
```

Comment: That won't have putIfAbsent (or a set equivalent).

Comment: But putIfAbsent is not for Sets, for Set add works as putIfAbsent: add(E e) - Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present